# React Material UI table add custom button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

This is a question specific to [MaterialTable](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#material-table).  I have gone through the docs and the API but can not find an efficient way to customize the `Actions` column and add an icon for view details.

I am working with a relational database and would like to be able to link it for each user on their row.

[image: Add Button after trash can]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Material Table documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/actions) states that you can pass an array of actions to the `actions` prop on the `MaterialTable` component.

Each action element in the array can have fields specified, which include `icon` and `onClick`. `icon` can be a custom component.

Here's the example from the documentation linked above:

```js
<MaterialTable
  // other props
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'save',
      tooltip: 'Save User',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        // Do save operation
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: Sir there are no words I could conjure up which would adequately articulate my gratitude.   So I will just say: Perfect!